# Interpretation of CachedStorageObject error while querying Kusto table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am running a query from follower cluster pointing to the table that exists on the leader cluster and get the following error:-

`Partial query failure: An unexpected error occurred. (message: 'StorageException with HttpStatusCode 503 was thrown.: : : ', details: 'Source: Kusto::CachedStorageObject'`)

Since the error seems to be related to cache , I am trying to understand exactly how to interpret it? If something is not found in the follower cache, ADX should have automatically got the data from leader storage right , I don't quite see why it should fail. It's not quite clear what the error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the `StorageException with HttpStatusCode 503`, this appears to be a transient failure in accessing underlying storage objects.

If the issue persists, I would recommend that you open a support ticket for your resource, via the Azure portal.